# Background processing: how to check if object still exists upon completion

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an object `MyClass` that is launching some background processing in a detached thread.

Inside `MyClass` header file:

```
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> loadingThread;
```

Inside `MyClass` impl file:

```
    loadingThread.reset(new std::thread(&MyClass::acquireFileModel, this));
    loadingThread->detach();
```

In the `acquireFileModel` method, we make a synchronous call that takes a while to complete. During this time, the `MyClass` instance may be destroyed (it relates to a certain page in the UI being left).

How should I check that my instance is still actually there after the synchronous call has completed? I can't do anything with the data and should just give up if the object instance that launched the background thread has gone.

Should I be launching the work from another object that has a weak pointer to the `MyClass` and hence I can check the pointer afterwards to know if the object still exists?

Comment: You must make sure that the `MyClass` instance exists until the thread is done. You can either give ownership to the thread or `join` with the thread (meaning no `detach`ing) in `~MyClass` or find some other way to do this. You didn't give enough context to be more specific.

Comment: @nwp "Give ownership to the thread" - are you referring to `std::move`? How would that look?

Comment: For other reasons (OpenGL basically), I want to destroy the object as soon as it goes out of scope. So my emphasis is more on "realise the object is gone if it's gone".

Comment: Something like `MyClass m; loadingThread.reset(new std::thread(&MyClass::acquireFileModel, std::move(m)));` should work.

Comment: shared_ptr and weak_ptr might be an option for you. Or simply setting a flag to signal if the object pointer is still valid.